# How do i print the first index of every list except for the header row?

Tags: python

```
grades = [
    ['Student', 'Exam 1', 'Exam 2', 'Exam 3'],
    ['Thorny', '100', '90', '80'],
    ['Mac', '88', '99', '111'],
    ['Farva', '45', '56', '67'],
    ['Rabbit', '59', '61', '67'],
    ['Ursula', '73', '79', '83'],
    ['Foster', '89', '97', '101']
]
```

I want to create a new list named `Students` which has all the student names except for the header.

I tried:

```
students = [item[0] for item in grades]
```

but this gives me the header "students" as well.

Comment: Perhaps `[item[0] for item in grades[1:]]`

Comment: `for i in grades[1:]:
    print(i[0])` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're close. You simply need to limit the `grades` in your statement:

```
students = [item[0] for item in grades[1:]]
```

This will iterate over `grades` starting with the second item (index of 1) to the end (nothing after the `:`).

Comment: Great thank you!! And if I wanted to print everything from the header row except for the word "Student", how would I do that?

Comment: @Natalie `grades[0]` will get you the first row, so `grades[0][1:]` would get you the set of headers following "Student".

Answer (score 0):

Just throw away the first line.

```
 students = students[1:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The above solution uses list comprehansion. This solution utilizes a more comon way you'd see it being writen in other programming languages.

```
  students = []
  for data in grades[1:]:
      students.append(data[0])
```

Comment: Thank you! And if I wanted to print everything from the header row except for the word "Student", how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Although it has been answered but if headers are not sorted and occurs at some other position:

```
# Look for header containing certain string
header = lambda s: "Student" not in s

# Get everything from the list except containing header
students = [i for i in grades if header(i)]
```